# hardhat dependency not picked up by heroku/vercel

Tags: node.js, express, solidity, hardhat

I built a Minting API using hardhat. I want to host it on heroku/vercel.
However I get the below error on deployment.
Error: Cannot find module 'hardhat'

I am using node.js, express.js

I have the below require.
`const hre = require("hardhat");`

My code works perfectly fine on localhost.

Comment: You need to install your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Do check if the 'hardhat' is under devDep or dep. It should be under dep in package.json.